# How to write unit test with jest for function that run command with spawn module And it has no return?

Tags: node.js, jestjs, spawn

For example I have function like this:

```
const interfaceAddAddress = (tag, ip) => { 

  spawn('bash', ['-c', `ip addr add ${ip} dev ${tag}`]);

};
```

How to writ unit test with jest for it?